# Can not implicitly convert type error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I am using entity framework to access database and trying to use my productModel class inside product class. but some how getting convert type error.

**Error:Cannot implicitly convert type 'SporLife.Product' to 'SporLife.Pages.Product'**

**this is my ManageProduct class**

```
namespace SporLife.Pages.Management
{
    public partial class ManageProduct : System.Web.UI.Page 
     {
       private void FillPage(int id)
        {
            //set selected product from DB
            ProductModel model = new ProductModel();
            Product product = model.GetProduct(id);//error appears here

            //Fill textBoxes
            txtDescription.Text = product.Description;
            txtName.Text = product.Name;
            txtPrice.Text = product.Price.ToString();
}}}
```

**This is my ProductModel class**

```
namespace SporLife.Models
{
    public class ProductModel
    {

  public Product GetProduct(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SporLifeDBEntities2 db = new SporLifeDBEntities2())
                {
                    Product product = db.Products.First(i => i.ID == id);
                    return product;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the `return` type of the object of the method is not matching the object where you are using this :

```
Product product = model.GetProduct(id);//error appears here
```

You will have to explicitly specify which object you want it to be like this :

```
SporLife.Product product = model.GetProduct(id);
```

and same in your method as :

```
public SporLife.Product GetProduct(int id)
```

I have used `SporLife` as an example. If you want `SporLife.Pages` as the return type, you might as well use that. The thing here is to specify the exact return type in both the cases so that they match.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially, two different types of `Product`, `SporLife.Product` and `SporLife.Pages.Product`. The `model.GetProduct(id)` returns a 'SporLife.Product' so if that is ok, you need to change the calling code to expect that. Maybe specify the type explicitly.

```
SporLife.Product product = model.GetProduct(id);//error appears here
```

Comment: SporLife.Pages.Product  product = SporLife.Models.ProductModel.GetProduct(id); //this is the extentions of classes.

Comment: which product does `db.Products` int the `GetProduct(int id)` method return?